# Input mask for decimal with jquery

Tags: jquery

My case is, I have an input which is to define total hour of user's working. I want to create input mask with placeholder like this :

xxx.00

So, if user just input `0` it will be automatically `0.00`.
The user can input like `0.5` that will be automatically `0.50`
I use inputmask like this :
I know its like time, but time just provide untill 24 like this

```
$(".time").inputmask("hh:mm", {"placeholder": "hh.mm"});
```

But I want to hh is flexible. like`125.00`. for any solution, so appreciated

Comment: can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862009/make-an-html-number-input-always-display-2-decimal-places

Comment: I have try it, but I want the sign '.' or decimal still there that cannot deleted

Comment: `var result  = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2);`