# Html input type of number allows multiple decimals

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am having an input box of type number in my html page in that it allows multiple decimal places rather than accepting only one decimal place can anyone tell me why it occurs like this and how to overcome this issue.

Html:

```
<input stopccp focus-me class="inputContainer" type="number" name=""
       ng-model="vm.total_amount[$index]" ng-change="vm.onTotalCost()"
       limit-char limit="5">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow 2 decimal places in <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number)

Comment: Hope this help! [Make an html input display 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862009/make-an-html-number-input-always-display-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

You Simply Add:

** step = ".01"**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="interest" placeholder="Interest" step=".01">
```

I Thinks That Should Work in Your case.

Comment: I think it's of comment quality