# add .00 at the end of value while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working a simple field where only accepts numbers, what I want is to add ".00" at the end of the value while I'm typing. ex. 1000.00.

the problem I cant achieve that format, after 1 digit it adds '.00' and cant type anymore.

I tried the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862009/make-an-html-number-input-always-display-2-decimal-places) but didn't work.

here is my [sample work](https://jsfiddle.net/gxv7rabp/7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input").keyup(function(){

        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        $(this).val(val.toFixed(2));

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$( 'input' ).on( 'input', function() {
  var val = $( this ).val(),
      arr = val.split( '.' );

  if ( arr.length > 1 )
    $( this ).val( arr[ 0 ] + val.substr( val.length - 1 ) + '.00' )
  else
    $( this ).val( val + '.00' )
} ).on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
  return e.charCode == 46 || ( e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57 )
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use blur function like this:

```
$("input").blur(function(){

    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(val){
        $(this).val(val.toFixed(2));
    }else{
        $(this).val(0);
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to do is type `1` and immediately get `1.00`, then type `2` and you will get `12.00`, then you need to save cursor position (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086190/2730688)).

- So you want to get current cursor position
- format the input data
- update `input` element
- restore cursor position in needed place (depending on where it should be moved)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try focusout event..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").focusout(function(){

         var val = parseInt($(this).val());
         $(this).val(val.toFixed(2));
     });
});
```