# Display a number with 2 decimal places in a number input

Tags: html, angular

I have an input which goes from min: 0 to max: 1. The default value is 1. I need it to display as 1.00 however. How can I do this?

Input html:

```
<input id="scale"
       name="scale"
       class="ui-g-9"
       type="number"
       [min]="0"
       [step]="0.01"
       [max]="1"
       [required]="true"
       [(ngModel)]="product.scale" <!-- this default value is 1.00 -->
       placeholder="Enter the scale">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an html number input always display 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862009/make-an-html-number-input-always-display-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @JayantJeetTomar No it's not a duplicate, that question is about angular js. And the solution also doesn't work when there is a default value. It works only when I go -1 to 0.99 and then +1 to 1.00

Comment: just change ```[(ngModel)]="product.scale"``` to ```[(ngModel)]="parseFloat(product.scale).toFixed(2)"```

Comment: @JayantJeetTomar type of product.scale is number. parseFloat doesn't work on numbers.

Comment: Even better. use ```[(ngModel)]="(product.scale).toFixed(2)"```

Comment: @JayantJeetTomar Doesn't work. I get errors: `Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 30 in [(ivcProduct.scale).toFixed(2)=$event] in ng:///IvcModule/IvcProductDialogComponent.html@35:19 ("roup>
        <app-control-group fieldName="contact" label="Scale" labelClass="ui-g-3">
            [ERROR ->]<input #scale id="scale"
                   name="scale"
                   class="ui-g-9"
"): ng:///IvcModule/IvcProductDialogComponent.html@26:12, Directive NgControlStatus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using @ViewChild in the component to get the reference to the input element:

```js
export class Component implements AfterViewChecked {
    @ViewChild('scale') scaleInput;

    /**
     * Angular after view checked handler
     */
    ngAfterViewChecked(): boolean {
        // Display the default value: 1 with 2 decimal places: 1.00
        this.scaleInput.nativeElement.value = parseFloat(this.scaleInput.nativeElement.value).toFixed(2);

        return super.ngAfterViewChecked();
    }
}
```

Where the html input is now:

```html
            <input #scale <!-- IMPORTANT PART -->
                   id="scale"
                   name="scale"
                   class="ui-g-9"
                   type="number"
                   (input)="setTo2FractionalDigits($event)"
                   [min]="0"
                   [step]="0.01"
                   [max]="1"
                   [required]="true"
                   [(ngModel)]="ivcProduct.scale"
                   placeholder="Enter the scale">
```

Answer (score -2):

**Step 1:** Edit your input tag

```
<input id="scale"
       name="scale"
       class="ui-g-9"
       type="number"
       onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal"
       [min]="0"
       [step]="0.01"
       [max]="1"
       [required]="true"
       [(ngModel)]="(product.scale).toFixed(2)" <!-- this default value is 1.00 -->
       placeholder="Enter the scale">
```

**Step 2:** Write the setTwoDecimalPlace method

```
function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get errors: `Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 30 in [(ivcProduct.scale).toFixed(2)=$event] in ng:///IvcModule/IvcProductDialogComponent.html@35:19 ("roup>         <app-control-group fieldName="contact" label="Scale" labelClass="ui-g-3">             [ERROR ->]<input #scale id="scale"                    name="scale"                    class="ui-g-9" "): ng:///IvcModule/IvcProductDialogComponent.html@26:12, Directive NgControlStatus`